# Inverse of a bounded operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inverse

Consider a bounded (linear) operator $T \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ on a Hilbert space $H$. We say $T$ is invertible if it has a bounded inverse, i.e. if $\exists T^{-1} \in \mathcal{L}(H)$ such that $T^{-1} T = T T^{-1} = I \in \mathcal{L}(H)$.

It is easy to see that, if $T$ is invertible, then $T$ is bounded from below, meaning that

$$ \exists c >0 : \, \| Tx \| \geq c \| x \| \, , \quad \forall x \in H $$

(one can take $c = 1/\| T^{-1} \|$). My question is: does the converse hold? i.e. does boundedness from below imply invertibility? If no, can you give an example of a $T$ which is bounded from below but not invertible?

Comment: If the image of $T$ is dense then it is true, since being bounded from below implies injective and closed range. A sufficient condition would be coercivity, that is,  $(Tx,x) \ge c (x,x)$ for some constant $c$ and all $x$, which is stronger than boundedness from below.

Comment: Every two separable Hilbert spaces are isometrically isomorphic. So your question can be transformed into $T:H_1\to H_2,$ where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are separable Hilbert spaces. Let $H_1=H$ and $H_2=H\times H.$ Define $Th=(h,0).$ Then $T$ is an isometry and not invertible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $H = \ell_2(\mathbb{N})$, and let $T$ be the shift operator $T(x_1, x_2, \ldots) = (0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$.  Then $\Vert Tx \Vert = \Vert x \Vert$ for all $x$, but $T$ is not surjective so it isn't invertible.